# Gulp sass returning Error: python2 not found

Tags: npm, cmd, gulp-sass

[image]
[image]

This is what I see when I try to install gulp-sass like this:

```
npm i gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Running `gulp-watch` and `gulp browser-sync` works

TIA

Answer (score 5):

As the error message suggests you probably don't have python installed. The `node-sass` library compiles the `libsass` from source. For that it uses [`node-gyp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp). To build under windows the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp#on-windows) suggests:

> ## On Windows
>
> ### Option 1
>
> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using npm install --global --production windows-build-tools from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
>
> ### Option 2
>
> #### Install tools and configuration manually:
>
> - Install Visual C++ Build Environment: [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools) (using "Visual C++ build tools" workload) or [Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pl/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community) (using the "Desktop development with C++" workload)
> - Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (v3.x.x is not supported), and run npm config set python python2.7 (or see below for further instructions on specifying the proper Python version and path.)
> - Launch cmd, npm config set msvs_version 2017
>
> If the above steps didn't work for you, please visit [Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules) for additional tips.
>
> If you have multiple Python versions installed, you can identify which Python version node-gyp uses by setting the '--python' variable:
>
> ```
> node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7
> ```
>
> If node-gyp is called by way of npm and you have multiple versions of Python installed, then you can set npm's 'python' config key to the appropriate value:
>
> ```
> npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
> ```